# How to pass an array to ajax and access in controller?

Tags: arrays, ajax, laravel

I have an array

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

How can i pass this array to ajax and get it from controller?

```
  $(document).on('click', '#print', function(){
        var code = $(this).attr('data-code');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'print',
            data: {code: code,option: array here},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                w = window.open(window.location.href,"_blank");
                w.document.open();
                w.document.write(html);
                w.document.close();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use get method for sending an array.

Answer (score 1):

How about an ajax post request

```
  $(document).on('click', '#print', function() {
        var code = $(this).attr('data-code');
        var a =[1,2,3,4,5]

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/print',
            data: {code: code,option: a,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (html) {
                w = window.open(window.location.href,"_blank");
                w.document.open();
                w.document.write(html);
                w.document.close();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
```

In your routes

```
Route::post('/print', 'SomeController@specifiedControllerMethod);
```

Then you can access it on your controller using

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function specifiedControllerMethod(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: For example var a =[1,2,3,4,5], then i want pass it to ajax data :{option:a}, but if i do so, when click on the button, it shows no respond.

Comment: in network tab does it show that the request proceeds?

Comment: In network tab show nothing, but in console show error like this Error: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), 11 more… }

Comment: did you change the datatype to json?